# Use different GoogleService-Info.plist for different build schemes

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, google-signin

I am using a build scheme for prod and one for staging (with 2 different bundle identifiers) and I am trying to use a separate GoogleService-Info.plist for each scheme.
Is there any way to manually select the plist file to use when initialising GCM (and goole login)? Or is its possible to avoid using the plist and do the setup manually?

Thanks!

Comment: You use two different targets? Then have different files (with same name) in different Copy Bundle Resources (that in build phases).

Comment: That article was helpful for me https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709334/11537677

Comment: Firebase Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Answer (score 239):

### Details

Tested on:

- Xcode 9.2
- Xcode 10.2 (10E125)
- Xcode 11.0 (11A420a)

### Solution

1. Create folder with all your Google.plist files (with different names) in project

[image]

2. Add run script

[image]

> Do not forget to change **PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS** value

**Code**

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/SM2/Application/Firebase"

case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

   "Debug_Staging" | "AdHoc_Staging" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

   "Debug_Production" | "AdHoc_Production" | "Distribution" | "Test_Production" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-prod.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac
```

> Build schemes names

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer. Apparently Firebase Analytics requires that plist file in your app's root directory, even if you call `configure(options:)`. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/5

Comment: This is a very nice solution and should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Just wondering if this should be cp -r or just cp? Is it a directory?

Comment: @smileBot you may skip `-r`, more info: [cp command in Linux/Unix](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/cp.html)

Comment: `case "${CONFIGURATION}" in "Debug" )
cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Staging-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" 
;;
"Release" )
cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" 
;;
*)
cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Staging-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" 
;;
esac`    I did this but it always taking GoogleService-Staging-Info.plist in both mode (Debug & Release). Anything wrong here??

Comment: where did you put the run script? I have mine put before Copy Bundle Resources but it gives me an error `error: Build input file cannot be found: '<path_to_root>/GoogleService-Info.plist'`

Comment: @mikey I placed this code before Copy Bundle Resources. Did you add base googleservice-info.plist to your project? This script will replace already added googleservice-info.plist.

Comment: Thank you @VasilyBodnarchuk, I think the problem I had, is that I didn't add googleservice-info to my project, and also I had another script deleting the file at the end of the build phase (I wanted to make sure to get a fresh copy on every build). I ended up doing this `cp -v "sorcerers-gold/Config/GoogleService-Info-"$FIREBASE_ENVIRONMENT".plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"` and having using the FIREBASE_ENVIRONMENT to decide which file to pick up

Comment: Can I use two Firebase projects from one xcode project simultaneously? Not as Debug & Release? Cause when I try to do this I always end up with already configured crash. I have followed the latest instruction from Firebase official document. I am still searching for how can I configure two separate Firebase Project at the same time. Or how could I unconfigure one and then configure another one? Thanks

Comment: @Tulon I think, it is possible to keep two plists in a project. But, you will have to switch configuration of the firebase in project, because you can’t setup two firebases in the app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52964211

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk, Actually I did. Just configured two of them in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` one after another by following Firebase's official documentation. The main thing is I had to call both `configue` func only once in the life cycle of that app. Prior I was trying to call them in `viewDidload` of a certain `viewController`. So it was giving objection. Thanks

Comment: I didn't find the 'Application' folder and my schemes names were standard, so I had to adjust the script to make it work: I placed the Firebase folder inside YourAppName and used "Debug" and "Release" as scheme names: `PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/YourAppName/Firebase"

case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

   "Debug" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

   "Release" )
        cp -r "
...
`

Comment: Right now I m getting error. Please help me to resolve this.

GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist

GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Development/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

   "Debug (Development)" | "Release (Development)" )
       cp “${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}” “${PLIST_DESTINATION}” ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk Yes provided. But still not getting crash logs on firebase.

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Development/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_QAT=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/QAT/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
case "${CONFIGURATION}" in
"Debug (Dev)" | "Release (Dev)" )
       cp -r "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;
"Debug (QAT)" | "Release (QAT)" )
       cp -r "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_QAT}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;   *) ;;
esac

Comment: @HimaniSharma ok. Can you compile and run your project? If no, what error Xcode sends to you? If yes, run your project in simulator and find all "firebase" in logs. You can try to understand what is going on. P.S. also update firebase pod.

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk i have added the script, given the appropriate path, added the script before copy bundle resources but it crashes with the error 'FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project.

Comment: @UsamabinAttique do you need the sample of this project?

Comment: I had an issue where when adding the two plist to the project it has also added to copy resource build phase as well, which resulted in `Multiple commands produce ...plist` error     to overcome this I had to remove the plist from copy resource build pace. more info can be found in this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce

Comment: Excellent. I turned this into a one-liner by adding a user-defined build setting called `GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST` and setting it to the path I wanted to use for each configuration. Then the script is just `cp "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"`.

Comment: This solution worked great for a flutter / dart application since most flutter apps have multiple schemes and one single target.

Answer (score 95):

@inidona 's answer worked for me. After I converted it to Swift

for Swift 2.3:

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
FIRApp.configureWithOptions(options)
```

for Swift 3.0:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")!
let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
FIRApp.configure(with: options)
```

for Swift 4.0:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")!
let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options!)
```

Comment: With the above code, do you have two different files `GoogleService-Info.plist` files at different locations or may two files with different names. Could you please provide some more information on what are the actual file names and where are they placed?

Comment: I have 2 files named
GoogleService-Info-dev.plist
GoogleService-Info-live.plist
this code allows you to tell ur app whick info file you want to work with instead of the default GoogleService-Info-dev.plist
use conditional statement or target flags to alternate between your files

Comment: yup, in the AppDelegate

Comment: gives me 'Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist''

Comment: Recent document says "Warning: This approach can impact Analytics collection in some circumstances" https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Comment: And in the same document they say it's "If the builds are part of a single target, the best option"

Comment: This is not the recommended approach! You WILL miss any metric, crash, or analytic that needs uploaded from the point your app launches to the point your app initializes the .plist.

ONLY do this if you are not uploading any metric or log before initialization (e.g. Crashalytics)

Answer (score 52):

If the `GoogleService-Info.plist` has a different name it will affect your analytics results. [Firebase will warn you about this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/230#issuecomment-327138180). For this reason, none of these runtime-solutions will provide the best analytics results.

There are two solutions that won't mess with Analytics.

1. **Use a different target with each scheme** and associate each version of `GoogleService-Info.plist` with its own target. See **Target Membership** in the **File inspector** on the right hand side in Xcode. For further info [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683958/using-google-sign-in-with-two-targets?noredirect=1&lq=1).
2. **Use a build phase script to copy the correct version** of `GoogleService-Info.plist` into the build directory. I use a different bundle ID for staging and production. This enables me to have both versions of the app installed in parallel. It also means with the script below I can name my different `GoogleService-Info.plist` files with the bundle ID. For example:

- `GoogleService-Info-com.example.app.plist`
- `GoogleService-Info-com.example.app.staging.plist`

### Build Phase Script

```
PATH_TO_CONFIG=$SRCROOT/Config/GoogleService-Info-$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER.plist
FILENAME_IN_BUNDLE=GoogleService-Info.plist
BUILD_APP_DIR=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo cp $PATH_TO_CONFIG "$BUILD_APP_DIR/$FILENAME_IN_BUNDLE"
cp $PATH_TO_CONFIG "$BUILD_APP_DIR/$FILENAME_IN_BUNDLE"
```

Note: You will have to change `PATH_TO_CONFIG` to suit you setup.

[image: Build Phase Script]

Comment: This is the best solution so far. Because Firebase Crashlytics can only use GoogleService-Info.plist file to upload dSYM files using 'upload-symbols' script - this solution works perfectly!

Comment: I confirm this solution also works with Firebase Crashlytics installed through Swift Package Manager.

Comment: @onato I've tried a similar way but, after adding crashlytics. It's not working. I got the below error. ```Error (Xcode): Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment```

Answer (score 37):

Check this article: https://medium.com/@brunolemos/how-to-setup-a-different-firebase-project-for-debug-and-release-environments-157b40512164

On Xcode, create two directories inside your project: `Debug` and `Release`. Put each `GoogleService-Info.plist` file there.

On `AppDelegate.m`, inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, put the code:

**Objective-C**

```
  NSString *filePath;
#ifdef DEBUG
  NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Development mode.");
  filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"Debug"];
#else
  NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Production mode.");
  filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"Release"];
#endif

  FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

**Swift 4**

```
var filePath:String!
#if DEBUG
    print("[FIREBASE] Development mode.")
    filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist", inDirectory: "Debug")
#else
    print("[FIREBASE] Production mode.")
    filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist", inDirectory: "Release")
#endif

let options = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
```

Drag & drop both `Debug` and `Release` folders to the `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`:

[image: Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources]

That's it :)

Comment: This worked for me. You have to add these folders there as reference, otherwise it will crash, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: This solution still doesn't solve the issue for `Analytics` framework, you cannot tell which `.plist` is being loaded.

Comment: @Bruno Lemos, Can I use two Firebase projects from one xcode project simultaneously? Not as `Debug` & `Release`? Cause when I try to do this I always end up with `already configured crash.` I have followed the latest instruction from Firebase official document. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

I think you can use this way to configure your GoogleService-Info.plist dynamicly and use different names for different bundle identifiers.

ciao
Andreas

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

Comment: With the above code, do you have two different files GoogleService-Info.plist files at different locations or may two files with different names. Could you please provide some more information on what are the actual file names and where are they placed?

Comment: I am gettin this error in log during configureWithOptions call: `Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'`

Answer (score 28):

This answer is very much inspired by [@abbood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766570/abbood)'s answer, but a bit more specific on how to do it.

For each of your targets, e.g. dev, stg, prod:

- Download the corresponding `GoogleService-Info.plist` to a separate folder named after your target
- In Xcode, right-click your app folder and choose `Add files to "your app"`
  [image]
- Select the folder containing the target's `GoogleService-Info.plist`, make sure `Copy items if needed` and `Create groups` are selected, check only the corresponding target in the list of targets, and press `Add`
  [image]

That's it. Now you should have something similar to this structure

[image]

When you build a target, the correct `GoogleService-Info.plist` will be used.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: No need for custom script. Perfect.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much easier to do and maintain this way

Comment: Actually, these are for different built targes. The question is how to do for schemas not target. But this seems the ideal way to go

Comment: I have been trying to do this for days and this worked flawlessly. Just make sure to delete any other references to the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` or you might get: `error: Multiple commands produce GoogleServices-Info.plist...`

Comment: I ran into this problem for different Targets, and this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 22):

I noticed that google expects the filename to be GoogleServiceInfo.plist in the code:

```
 * The method |configureWithError:| will read from the file GoogleServices-Info.plist bundled with
 * your app target for the keys to configure each individual API. To generate your
 * GoogleServices-Info.plist, please go to https://developers.google.com/mobile/add
 *
 * @see GGLContext (Analytics)
 * @see GGLContext (SignIn)
 */
@interface GGLContext : NSObject
```

the key phrase is this one

> read from the file GoogleServices-Info.plist bundled with your app target

So I simply copied the same file and put it into different directories, and bounded it to different targets:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very simple and works very well for me, Xcode 10.1, FirebaseCore (5.3.1)

Comment: How to avoid "Multiple command produce" error which occur after because of multiple Plist or other files within App

Comment: Works great! So simple. Can't believe "write a script that changes the filename at build time" answers are voted higher than this.

Answer (score 21):

Late but I think I must post this answer to help new developers, I found a very good article that resole my problem and I promise it can help you as well :)
Check [this](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0) article that resolve your problem as well.

**Step 1:**
Copy the **GoogleService-Info.plist** corresponding to your Firebase development environment into the **Dev** directory. Similarly, copy the **GoogleService-Info.plist** corresponding to your Firebase production environment in the **Prod** directory. Make sure to uncheck **“Copy items if needed”** and all targets under **“Add to targets”**.

[image: (Step 1 image link (I do not able to add image because of less reputations))]

**Step 2:**
In the Xcode project navigator, select the app target. Switch to the Build Phases tab at the top, then add a **New Run Script Phase**. Name the phase **“Setup Firebase Environment GoogleService-Info.plist”**, or something to that effect, and place it before the **“Copy Bundle Resources”** step.

**Step 3:**
Implement a shell script that will copy the appropriate **GoogleService-Info.plist** into the app bundle based on the build configuration. Copy and paste the following shell script into the run script phase you just created:

```
# Name of the resource we're selectively copying
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist

# Get references to dev and prod versions of the GoogleService-Info.plist
# NOTE: These should only live on the file system and should NOT be part of the target (since we'll be adding them to the target manually)
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Dev/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Prod/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

# Make sure the dev version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV ]
then
    echo "No Development GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure the prod version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD ]
then
    echo "No Production GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo "Will copy ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} to final destination: ${PLIST_DESTINATION}"

# Copy over the prod GoogleService-Info.plist for Release builds
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]
then
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
else
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
fi
```

Comment: @mashhood 
i am getting compiler if follow your mention steps.

Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

Answer (score 15):

I found that in case of single target the only 100% viable way is to copy plist corresponding to build configuration during the build; but such answers here differ in details of how to do it, and no one was convenient enough for me. My answer is based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709334/5272316) by @KnightFighter and [this](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0) article on Medium.

---

Firstly add all different plists to project with different names (they must not be added to target as resources):

[image]

Next create user-defined build setting, where you can assign specific plist to each build configuration:

[image]

Finally add "Run script" phase with code:

```
GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_SOURCE=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FILENAME}

if [ ! -f $GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_SOURCE ]
then
    echo "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_SOURCE} not found."
    exit 1
fi

GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"

cp "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_SOURCE}" "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION}"
```

---

I think such way has some advantages:

- no need to have folders hierarchy to store plists;
- no need to duplicate file if single plist is used for several configurations;
- it's easier to change filename in build settings than edit script if you need to add configuration or reassign plists; especially for non-programmers (i e build manager).

Comment: I use multiple schemes & configurations (with only one target) so this solution works great for me. Thank for a very detail explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Let's suppose we have two configurations set, `develop` and `production`. You have to make two things:

1. Rename both plists to conform to given configuration:

- GoogleService-Info-develop.plist
- GoogleService-Info-production.plist

2. Add a run script which copies the correct plist for selected configuration:

```
FIREBASE_PLIST_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}/App/Resources/Plists/GoogleService-Info-${CONFIGURATION}.plist"
echo "Firebase plist path: ${FIREBASE_PLIST_PATH}"
cp -r ${FIREBASE_PLIST_PATH} "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

A run script needs to be positioned before `FirebaseCrashlytics` script.

You you can init firebase as you did before for single scheme: `FirebaseApp.configure()`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot avoid to use the plist with Firebase. The best solution I found so far for you it would be to add both files and name it

> GoogleService-Info_stage.plist

and

> GoogleService-Info_prod.plist

Then from your code you can call the correct file. This way won't crash your app if you don't have the file. Just replace FILENAME with GoogleService-Info_prod or GoogleService-Info_stage.

```
if let configFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FILENAME", ofType: "plist"), 
    let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: configFile)   
{
   FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
}
```

Comment: Runtime configurations can lead to analytics reporting issues as mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

Comment: this will issue with dsym file forCrashlytic.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by this:

```
    #if STAGING
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-Dev", ofType: "plist"),
            let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
                FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
        } else {
            fatalError("GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist is missing!")
        }
    #else
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist"),
            let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
                FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
        } else {
            fatalError("GoogleService-Info.plist is missing!")
        }
    #endif
```

Comment: Absolutely the easiest and most straight forward way of doing this.

Answer (score 6):

So I have pondered the same question and using some ideas from earlier posts, some of which publish apps with `GoogleServices-Info.plist` for all environments in all apps and that is a bit of a concern.

I have come up with an extensible solution that copies the `GoogleSerives-Info.plist` file at build time. Further more this approach can support as many environments as you like with the ability to customise and follows a simple convention, making it easy to manage.

First and foremost i have three environments, `debug` (For running in simulator and device whist debugging and actively cutting code), `staging` (for deployment to test flight) and `release` for production.

Step one is to create your configuration(s):

[image]

Select "Product" -> "Scheme" -> "Edit Scheme" and duplicate/create new as required. Go through each Scheme and assign its respective configuration from the
"Build Configuration" drop down in each of the categories:

[image]

I go a step further and uncheck "run" for Schemes that need to be distributed i.e. release and staging, and conversely uncheck "archive" for debug. You should do what makes sense for you.

[image]

Under build phases add the following run scrip (`CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER` variable can be customised as desired - just ensure you use the same folder name in the next step):

```
# Get a reference to the folder which contains the configuration subfolders.
CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER=Firebase
# Get a refernce to the filename of a 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file.
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
# Get a reference to the 'GoogleService-Info.plist' for the current configuration.
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/${CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER}/${CONFIGURATION}/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
# Check if 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file for current configuration exist.
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION ]
then
  echo "No '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}' file found for the configuration '${CONFIGURATION}' in the configuration directory '${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/${CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER}/${CONFIGURATION}'."
  exit 1
fi
# Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist.
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
# Copy 'GoogleService-Info.plist' for current configution to destination.
cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION}" "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION}"
echo "Successfully coppied the '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}' file for the '${CONFIGURATION}' configuration from '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION}' to '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION}'."
```

[image]

In your chosen configurations folder ("Firebase" in the above example) nest folders for each configuration named exactly the same as its respective configuration (case sensitive), inside of which place the respective `GoogleServices-Info.plist` files like so:

[image]

Last but not least, i also like to ensure that a root level `GoogleServices-Info.plist` is not added into the project by accident so I add the following to my .gitignore.

```
# Ignore project level GoogleService-Info.plist
/[Project Name]/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's my version of @Essam's solution.

1. Generate a GoogleServices version for the default scheme
   (`Google-Services.plist`) with the default identifier
2. Generate a second GoogleServices version
   for the variant scheme (`Google-Services-debug.plist`) with the correct identifier
3. Add both to
   the root of your project (where it tells you to in their guide)

Add this code where you'd add configure:

```
        let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
        if (bundleID!.contains("debug")) {
            let resource: String = "GoogleService-Info-debug"
            let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType: "plist")!
            let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: options!)
        } else {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution!

```
NSString *filePath;
if([self isProduction]){
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
}else{
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-Sandbox" ofType:@"plist"];
}
FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

And That's it!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not possible to achieve without using the `GoogleService-Info.plist.` Because before you can begin integrating your iOS app with the Google Sign-In components, you must download the dependencies and configure your Xcode project. 
And this [process](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating#add-config) shows that `GoogleService-Info.plist` has a big factor on it.

So the solutions and idea here in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683958/using-google-sign-in-with-two-targets) can help you with your problem. Just moved the main copy of the `GoogleService-Info plist` out of the app into 2 separate folders, then used the Build Phases "Copy Files" on each target to import the target specific plist into the Resources folder.

Also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118889/copy-file-to-root-of-xcode-project-when-building), it might give you more information/idea to your problem.

Comment: Here, does target mean a different scheme for the same project? After reading the questions, I gathered that the target mean a different build target altogether and not just a different build scheme for the same target.

Comment: But what if you have one target with a different configuration for each scheme?

Answer (score 3):

If some of you fall into an error and Xcode complains

> "Multiple commands produce GoogleService-Info.plist"

after applying @Knight Fighter [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709334/1352748), you may want to:

- Check **Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources**
- Filter for files named `GoogleService-Info.plist`
- Remove any references you have to it, since
  it's already being copied through the script.

Comment: Same idea as @Bjorn Egil's answer but more compact

Answer (score 3):

Place Your
GoogleService-Info-dev.plist,GoogleService-Info-prod.plist file in some folder in your root directory

eg:
[image: Place your files in some directory from your root]

Add Build Phase Script

```html
# Set the path to the googleServiceInfo folder
GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}/googleServiceInfo"

GENERATED_INFO_FILE_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}"

# Determine the appropriate GoogleService-Info.plist file based on the environment
if [[ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-dev" || "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-dev" ]]; then
    cp -r "$GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PATH/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" "$GENERATED_INFO_FILE_PATH/GoogleService-Info.plist"
elif [[ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-production" || "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-production" || "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Profile-production" ]]; then
    cp -r "$GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PATH/GoogleService-Info-prod.plist" "$GENERATED_INFO_FILE_PATH/GoogleService-Info.plist"
fi
```

Inside this script you can see build-variants, you can get from info Section
eg:
[image]

Don't Forget to add output files inside your build phase script

[image: Place Output files in your build phase script]

Move your build phase script(here its renamed as GoogleServiceInfo) above Compile Sources

Keynote: Check logs while running the build script.
Here, target name was Runner, you can change it according.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in Xamarin C#:

```
string plistPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource ("GoogleService-Info", "plist");
Options options = new Options (plistPath);
App.Configure (options);
```

Remember to include the Firebase namespace:

```
using Firebase.Analytics;
```

Answer (score 2):

!Finally it working for macOS App.

Thanks @vasily-bodnarchuk for his solution for iOS app.But for macOS app it needs little extra modification in script file.

Just append the designated resources directory for macOS "**Contents\Resources**". Please check for detail [Copy Bundle Resources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/customizing-the-build-phases-of-a-target?changes=_8)

**Code**

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/SM2/Application/Firebase"

case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

   "Debug_Staging" | "AdHoc_Staging" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

   "Debug_Poduction" | "AdHoc_Poduction" | "Distribution" | "Test_Poduction" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-prod.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 9.2, I have needed files for both targets to be named "googleServiceInfo.plist" but placed in different directories, with the directory/file for each target specified in "Build Phases", "Copy Bundle Resources".

The above was not my preferred solution, but I had previously tried using different filenames along the lines of @inidona's answer, converted to Swift 4:

```
 let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "googleServiceInfo-Pro", ofType: "plist")!
 let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
 FirebaseApp.configure(options: options!)
```

Unfortunately, this did not correct the Firebase error messages.   In this question: [Firebase iOS SDK - Using configuration file other than GoogleService-Info.plist generates console warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530027/firebase-ios-sdk-using-configuration-file-other-than-googleservice-info-plist?rq=1) the original poster seems to have fixed by updating the Firebase Pod but I have not confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

@Vasily Bodnarchuk answer worked for me. The only thing that you need to pay attention is that the scripts in Xcode have a precise order, so you need to put this script as first one, before the scripts with

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
```

and

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/<yourapp>/Configuration Files/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to do it in Fastlane.

You can use the file manager plugin for fastlane (fastlane-plugin-file_manager), to run a simple copy command.

1. Add a GoogleService-info-app.plist to your xcode project the standard way so it's linked properly.
2. Use copy files to overwrite this linked file with the files you want in your build / beta lane.

   copy_files(source: "firebase/GoogleService-Info-" + ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"] + ".plist", destination: "GoogleService-Info.plist")

Answer (score 1):

though late to the party, I have a solution implemented for this.
At first names your plists like below:
GoogleService-Info-target1

GoogleService-Info-target2

GoogleService-Info-target3

And then add the below Script in the Build Phases Tabs of each target by adding a new runs script phase:

> PATH_TO_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/(Folder Name containing
> all the plists)"  case "${TARGET_NAME}" in
>
> "target1 name" ) cp -r
> "$PATH_TO_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-target1.plist"
> "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
> ;;
>
> "target2 name" ) cp -r
> "$PATH_TO_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-target2.plist"
> "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
> ;;
>
> "target3 name" ) cp -r
> "$PATH_TO_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-target3.plist"
> "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
> ;;
>
> *) ;; esac

Answer (score 0):

For multiple schemes like Stage, QA, UAT and PROD with one target below script worked for me.
Also i have maintained .xcconfig files with their configuration name

```
 # Get a reference to the folder which contains the configuration 
   subfolders.
    CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER=Firebase
 # Get a refernce to the filename of a 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file.
    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
 # Get a reference to the 'GoogleService-Info.plist' for the current 
   configuration. ENV_NAME name is the folder name(Dev,QA,Uat,Prod) 
   which i have in my .xcconfig file for each environment.
    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}
    /${CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER}/${ENV_NAME}/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
 # Check if 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file for current configuration 
   exist.
    if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION ]
   then
    echo "No '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}' file found for the 
    configuration '${CONFIGURATION}' in the configuration directory 

    '${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/${CONFIGURATIONS_FOLDER}/
    ${CONFIGURATION}'."
   exit 1
 fi
  # Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService- 
    Info.plist.
     GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}
     /${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
  # Copy 'GoogleService-Info.plist' for current configution to 
    destination.
     cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION}" 
     "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION}"
     echo "Successfully coppied the '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}' file 
     for the '${CONFIGURATION}' configuration from 
     '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_LOCATION}' to 
     '${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST_DESTINATION}'."
```