# Use Two GoogleService-Info.plist in a single XCode project

Tags: ios, firebase, google-signin

I'm using Google Login and Google Firebase in my iOS Project. So I generated two different GoogleService-Info.plist files. If I use those two files under a project I got duplicate issue.

How to use these two files in a single project?

All Suggestions are appreciated!!

Comment: property list files are like XML based files, just merge them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `FirebaseApp.configure()` I use this method:

```
private func configureFirebase() {
    guard   let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-Firebase", ofType: "plist"),
            let options =  FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
    else { return }
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
}
```

So, for firebase you should create a new file e.g. `GoogleService-Info-Firebase.plist` and use it for Firebase configuration.