# How to avoid hardcoding REVERSED_CLIENT_ID into iOS Info.plist for dev/prod Google sign in?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am develop Flutter mobile app with Firebase.

I need separate Firebase environment for development and production.

I am follow this [guide](https://www.tengio.com/blog/multiple-firebase-environments-with-flutter/) for setup.

Issue is when I implement google authentication for iOS because in Runner [must copy `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` from `GoogleServices-Info.plist` into `Info.plist` file](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in).

I cannot just hardcode this `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` into `Info.plist` because it is different for my development and production environments.

Is there way to specify variable in `Info.plist` to get correct `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` for different environments?

I am use this script to copy correct `GoogleServices-Info.plist`:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-prod" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-prod" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/Prod/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Production plist copied"

elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-dev" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-dev" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/Dev/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Development plist copied"
fi
```

I look for answer everywhere but cannot find! I am completely block because of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this be creating a User-Defined variable that is environment specific and pull that variable into Info.plist

I setup my application to connect to two firebase projects (dev and prod) using instructions in this article: 
https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b

The thousand-foot summary is that you end up with a GoogleServices-Info.plist file for each dev and prod that is copied into the correct location at build time.

To set two REVERSE_CLIENT_IDS:

1. Create a User-defined variable by adding it to ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig and ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig.  I called mine: GOOGLE_SERVICE_REVERSE_CLIENT_ID = {REVERSE_CLIENT_ID found in GoogleService-Info.plist file}
2. Replace the hard-coded REVERSE_CLIENT_ID set in Info.plist with $(GOOGLE_SERVICE_REVERSE_CLIENT_ID)
3. Open your project in XCode and go to the User-defined section and set the actual environment specific REVERSE_CLIENT_ID for each build type. Targets > Runner > Build Settings > Search "user" > User-Defined >  GOOGLE_SERVICES_REVERSE_CLIENT_ID >

   Debug-dev = com.googleusercontent.apps.{dev client-id}
   Debug-prod = com.googleusercontent.apps.{prod client-id}
   Profile-dev = com.googleusercontent.apps.{dev client-id}
   Profile-prod = com.googleusercontent.apps.{prod client-id}
   Release-dev = com.googleusercontent.apps.{dev client-id}
   Release-prod = com.googleusercontent.apps.{prod client-id}

Answer (score 1):

My thought is, the way you have different GoogleService-Info.plist files for dev and prod environments, keep different Info.plist files with correct reverse client ids for dev and prod environments too. In your script include a line to copy the Info.plist file into iOS/Runner/ directory.

Comment: This isn't really an answer but commentary on another post. Please move this to the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make a comment but the nearest answer I could find is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48789232 (Below is an example modified for flutter, check your paths before following this!)

> 1. Create folder with all your Google.plist files (with different names) in project
> 2. Add a run script

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase"
    case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

   "Debug_Staging" | "AdHoc_Staging" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

   "Debug_Poduction" | "AdHoc_Poduction" | "Distribution" | "Test_Poduction" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-prod.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac
```

> 3. Build scheme names (in accordance to the different cases of ${CONFIGURATION} from above code)

4. Additionally you might have to add a default `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the Runner folder despite it being replaced by a copy from the script from the said link, should an notice pops up from the console where it asks about `Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.`

Answer (score 0):

For Swift development, you can add both your dev and prod `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID`s to your url schemes, and your app will use the one that you initialize in your `AppDelegate`.