# Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

For setting up firebase i am using two config 1.GoogleService-Info-test.plist, 2.GoogleService-Info-prdn.plist for UAT and Production. For installing crashlytics using firebase i have followed firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1#ios. But when i try to run, it throws error in build phase while running script.

I tried without changing config file name and it worked.

Error msg at build phase while running fabric run script "Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment".

Can anyone suggest better solution to achieve my requirement.

Comment: why does your file name have -test or -prdn in it?

Comment: try removing them

Comment: add one file at a time

Comment: make sure your project contains right `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is one way you can do it, by having your projects environments separated by targets, by doing so you can then add your different plist files and just check the target that they belong to, that way when you compile the target it will take it's corresponding plist file

[image: Sample Image]

Another way to do it, or to look up how to do it, it's called multiple environments with firebase, here are some helpful links

[Use different GoogleService-Info.plist for different build schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615405/use-different-googleservice-info-plist-for-different-build-schemes)

https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0

Comment: This is brilliant. This should be part of the FB documentation.

Comment: Don't create targets, use "build configurations" for this purpose.

Comment: @DanSkeel why? That sounds like the wrong tool for this task

Comment: @BenLeggiero because targets are designed for completely different apps (e.g. watch app), and not for configurations of same app. Thats why they have `build configurations` for this purpose. Main downside of this approach - in `pbxproj` file for each source file you get <numberOfTargets> duplicate lines that increase the complexity of resolving conflicts.

You can add user defined build setting with a name of the config file and use it in code to get proper file depending on build configuration.

Comment: Great reasoning! Thanks, @DanSkeel

Answer (score 36):

This worked for me:

When install Crashlytic with Firebase, for multiple scheme, you can have error `Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment`. You can fix it by:

- In `Build Settings`, add a user define for file name in `User Defined`:

[image: Add file name for each scheme in User Defined]

- In `Build Phases`, tap plus button, `New Run Script Phase` above your Crashlytic build phase, and type this code to the text field. Remember to rename %YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH_TO_FOLDER% to your path to Plist files:

```
GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FROM="${PROJECT_DIR}/%YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH_TO_FOLDER%/${FIREBASE_CONFIG_FILE}.plist"
BUILD_APP_DIR="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}"
GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_TO="${BUILD_APP_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
cp "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FROM}" "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_TO}"
```

[image: Add build phase]

Comment: To make it consistent : `GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FROM="${PROJECT_DIR}/%YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH_TO_FOLDER%/${FIREBASE_CONFIG_FILE}.plist"
BUILD_APP_DIR="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}"
GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_TO="${BUILD_APP_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
cp "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_FROM}" "${GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO_PLIST_TO}"` But this solution really works for multiple scheme sharing same target with different bundle ids as well.

Comment: I am getting the following error :

`unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' ` and 
` syntax error: unexpected end of file
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
`

Comment: @huync I am getting error while running this script 
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run What should be the input files path?

Comment: @Ollikas if you have faced the same issue & solved. please let know what is the input files path? I am getting the same error while running the script.

Answer (score 35):

This worked for me:

Make sure you add the Xcode Crashlytics build phase **after** Copy Bundle Resources.

Answer (score 33):

If you use Xcode 15 (beta as of 2023), you might have updated your project with `ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING`.

The default is YES, and this will cause the issue with Crashlytics during archive.

Go to Build Settings > User Script Sandboxing > Set to No.

Comment: Thanks for this! Since the recommended setting for "User Script Sandboxing" is Yes, is there a different solution?

Comment: Yeap, I faced the issue after accepting Xcode suggested configurations to enable user script sandboxing. Thanks for the Tip.

Answer (score 32):

I had this in my "Build Phases" and it's works

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/MyApp/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Comment: Adding `-gsp` and `-p` works for me. I moved the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to a different direcotry, so I have to use `-gsp` to specify the location.

Comment: This is my choosen solution. I use the CONFIGURATION variable to resolve the target like this:
`PLIST="${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Environment/${CONFIGURATION}`/GoogleService-Info.plist"

Comment: Where did you add these in Build Phases?

Comment: For Flutter users, I was able to make this work by going to XCode -> "Project Navigator" tab -> Runner -> highlight the Target "Runner" -> "Build Phases" tab -> find the "[firebase_crashlytics] Crashlytics Upload Symbols" step, and change it to `"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --flutter-project "$PROJECT_DIR/firebase_app_id_file.json" -gsp "$PROJECT_DIR/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME"` (previously it was `"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --flutter-project "$PROJECT_DIR/firebase_app_id_file.json"`).

Comment: Update as of November 2022:  This doesn't quite work for me, but if I remove the `upload-symbols` and instead put its parameters on the `run` command, it works.  The `run` script passes all of its parameters to `upload-symbols`, and apparently throws this error if `run` has no parameters.  At least for me.

Answer (score 22):

Our project only one target, but we need to use two Firebase config files `GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist` and `GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist`.

I had this in my "Build Phases" and it works.

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/RushCard/FirebaseConfig/GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist
else
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/RushCard/FirebaseConfig/GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist
fi
```

Comment: If you are using **SPM** then the script should be as follow: `if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then ${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/HERE_SET_YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/SupportingFiles/GoogleService-Info/GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist else ${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/HERE_SET_YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/SupportingFiles/GoogleService-Info/GoogleService-Info-Test.plist fi`

Comment: Slight typo in the SPM suggestion. Should be `if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then ${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/HERE_SET_YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/SupportingFiles/GoogleService-Info/GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist else ${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/HERE_SET_YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/SupportingFiles/GoogleService-Info/GoogleService-Info-Test.plist; fi`

Answer (score 10):

In my case I created **New Run Script Phrase** above **Compile Sources**, that's why I always see

> Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

When I moved Crashlytic's run script at the end of list bug was disappear. Please look the following screen shot:
[image]

And article about it is [here](https://medium.com/swlh/integrating-firebase-and-crashlytics-in-ios-complete-guide-updated-2019-4526e9ab9c6d)

Comment: I also followed the same steps, but still getting an error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment.

Answer (score 9):

I use multiple configurations for several white-labelled apps. I added a User-Defined variable `FIREBASE_SUFFIX` and changed my script to the following:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info-${FIREBASE_SUFFIX}.plist
```

NOTE: I use Carthage for firebase here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md. If you're this same setup, you should use something like this instead (replace the path to where you put your script files):

```
${PROJECT_DIR}/scripts/run -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info-${FIREBASE_SUFFIX}.plist
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to make sure one plist keeps the original name `GoogleService-Info.plist`

Different targets meant more work to update CI for me.

This is valid for Xcode 11 at least, not tested on any other versions

Comment: How can you be sure it will bind the Dsym to the relevant App then ? 
GOOGLE_APP_ID are different in the plist files if you have one bundle Id for Test and one for Prod.

Answer (score 6):

I was  using new Firebase/Crashlytics which beta and getting error "No Google App ID or Google Services file provided"  when I try to upload manually dSYMS

Here is command:

```
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
-gsp/path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

Then I reliaze there  should be space between "-gsp" and path to Google.plist  after that It worked.

Comment: what did you do with this command? Did you ran it in terminal? how do you get path to dSYMs?

Comment: You can get dsym with itunnes connect in build section... and Yes I run in terminal

Answer (score 6):

The solution for me was removing the call to upload-symbols script.

One of the Crashlytics guides mentions you should add this:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols  <- Not needed
```

I misinterpreted this... the run script already calls upload-symbols so there's no need to add a second call.

Comment: I am getting an error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

Comment: @ashwinitechnopurple make sure you added the plist from Firebase to your project and that it's also added to the correct app target

Comment: This worked for me. I removed this below line:
`"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --flutter-project "$PROJECT_DIR/firebase_app_id_file.json" `

And added this as the first line:
`"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure in Xcode file explorer (i.e on the left side) **"GoogleService-Info.plist"** is showing. If not you have to drag and drop "GoogleService-Info.plist" in the Xcode panel.

In my case problem is I copy-pasted the file in the project location, due to this file reference is missing in the Project info.

Answer (score 4):

Well all above answers purpose a possible solution for this issue, in my case GoogleService.plist file was missing from 'Copy Bundle Resources' by adding into it worked in my case..

To check the file goto

Project Directory >> Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources

add it add here if you find missing.

Answer (score 3):

If these solutions provided above do not work, I solved mine by going to Build phases as shown on this image. Click on plus and add Google plist

[image: Xcode screenshot solution]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by locate where is my GoogleService-Info.plist, copy it to ios folder in Flutter and run with this script

```
"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --flutter-project "$PROJECT_DIR/firebase_app_id_file.json" -gsp "$PROJECT_DIR/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME"
```

Update:
I found a better solution:

- Just upgrade all firebase package to lastest version
- Remove Crashlytics build script
- Run flutter clean, flutter pub get
- pod install (in ios folder)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I didn't download `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from Firebase console.
If you have your project on Firebase but missing this file in Xcode, don't worry, you don't need to do the setup again from the beginning. Just go to:
`Project Settings > General > Scroll down and in the "Your Apps" panel` you will see the file and you can download it and import it in the Xcode project.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for me:
I forgot to do **this installation step of crashlytics** before building my project.
https://rnfirebase.io/#generating-ios-credentials

- Using Xcode, open the projects /ios/{projectName}.xcodeproj file (or /ios/{projectName}.xcworkspace if using Pods).
- Right click on the project name and "Add files" to the project,
- Select the downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist file from your computer, and ensure the "Copy items if needed" checkbox is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, also due to the fact that I have multiple bundle identifier and therefore I have a build phase script called **Firebase Script** (that pinpoints to the correct **GoogleService-Info.plist** ) that was running after the **Crashlytics script**. 
The solution is to run **Firebase Script** *before* the **Crashlytics script**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a different name in my file, his name was **GoogleService-Enterprise-Info.plis** when I change it to the normal name **GoogleService-Info.plist**, IT WORK FINE !!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for @react-native-firebase/crashlytics

In case you are facing this issue, you probably have missed the 'ios setup' instruction mentioned in below link. Please follow the instruction to fix the issue.
https://rnfirebase.io/#generating-ios-credentials

Answer (score 0):

Just download from Settings of your projects and place for your correct target which you are running.

[image: plist file]

Answer (score 0):

This error would be shown if there is a space in your project name or in the path of your project.

Read more in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/557)

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help for me. In my case there is no spaces in path to the project, but still having this error.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to other answers..

I faced that problem with exact same error message and in my case everything was ok with file GoogleService-Info.plist except that it was genereated with wrong Bundle ID for application (it was changed in XCode much later than initial Firebase setup happened), so I had to create new app in Firebase Console with correct Bundle ID (it's not able to edit) and download new GoogleService-Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the [popular build scripts](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0) going around for handling multiple different environments, it is probably useful to know that you should use a different `GoogleService-Info.plist` destination based on the target platform:

```
// iOS
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app

// watchOS
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.appex

// macOS
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/Resources
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me after integrating `Firebase/Crashlytics`

and I added `GoogleService-Info.plist` file by copy/pasting this file into `iOS/[project-name]` folder,

And it should've been added by right-clicking `[project-name]` in xCode and select `Add file to [project-name]`

This will add the file `Build phases > Copy Bundle Resources`

Answer (score -1):

Ultimate guide:

1. Assure that in `Runner` folder you have file `GoogleService-Info.plist` and it is attached in your project

[image]

2. If you don't have this file go to Firebase Console, add you IOS app and download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, then add it to you project's Runner folder by XCode.
3. If there is no such file in XCode but it exists physically in the folder then right click on Runner folder (in Runner project) -> Add files to Runner -> Select that file
4. If you want to use multiple flavors add `ENV_SUFFIX` in Runner (target) -> Build Settings -> User-Defined (on the bottom)
   [image: 4]
5. Still in the target's Runner change tab to Build Phases -> Press Plus button -> New Run Script Phase -> Name it as `Copy GoogleService-Info.plist` and add this line
   `cp Runner/GoogleService-Info_${ENV_SUFFIX}.plist Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist`
   IMPORTANT! This script has to be before Initialize Crashlytics step or any other Firebase related script (you can drag it to the top)
   [image]
6. Add other GoogleService-Info.plist files with suffix for the env. In my case those would be the _dev _prod and _tst files from the first screen shot
7. Enjoy multiflavor app

Answer (score -5):

Try downgrading, it worked for me!
I used:
'Fabric', '1.9.0'
'Crashlytics', '3.12.0'

Comment: Everybody should always use the latest version of stable software. Old version software can have critical bugs and security issues.