# For Flutter project how to add firebase's GoogleService-Info.plist file in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter

i want to add different product flavor for dev and prod.
I have created two firebase project and added separately the google-service.json with created two folder inside src dev and prod
then how to can i add the GoogleService-Info.plist  file for IOS with dev and prod flavor in android studio (windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

You need Xcode to do it and it is so tricky. Unluckily the iOS part is not as easy as Android.

Here is a detailed answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48789232/5372178