# GoogleService-Info.plist in a multi-target project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift-package-manager

I have a firebase app that uses multiple modules so tests can run without needing to launch a simulator instance.

I've broken out my project into multiple spm targets, so my folder structure resembles the following:

```
MyApp
--- App
------ iOS
--------- ContentView.swift
--------- GoogleService-Info.plist
--- Sources
------ FirebaseClient
--------- FirebaseClient.swift
--- Tests
----- FirebaseClientTests
--------- FirebaseClientTests.swift
--- Package.swift
```

Calling `FirebaseApp.configure()` from `FirebaseClient.swift` works, but only so long as the main app is being run. If I try calling the setup function in `FirebaseClient.swift` from `FirebaseClientTests.swift`, I get the plist not found error. However, if I create a resources folder inside FirebaseClient, it can't find the plist in either executable. How can I set up the project so both the target and the test can find GoogleService-Info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Each test runs with a separate bundle identifier, so it's impossible to share the `GoogleService-Info.plist`s. You'll need to create a new `GoogleService-Info.plist` from firebase for your test (the bundle ID for the test will just be `FirebaseClientTests`). Take the test bundle ID and put it into the resources folder for FirestoreClient. If you don't have a resources folder, modify the folder structure of FirestoreClient to resemble the following:

```
--- Sources
------ FirebaseClient
--------- Resources
------------ GoogleService-Info.plist
--------- FirebaseClient.swift
```

and change the target definition in Package.swift to the following:

```
.target(
   name: "FirestoreClient",
   //    ...
   resources: [
      .process("Resources"),
   ]
),
```

Finally, you have to tell Firebase not to look in the main bundle for the plist when calling `FirebaseApp.configure`. Use the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39725837/998335) - just replace `Bundle.main` with `Bundle.module`.