# Add two GoogleService-Info.plist for Prod and dev build schemes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

before everything, I have already read this post
[Use different GoogleService-Info.plist for different build schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615405/use-different-googleservice-info-plist-for-different-build-schemes)

But still somehow it's not working for me.

I have two Prod and dev build schemes and I have two different `GoogleService-Info.plist`for them.

In my first attempt, I rename both google files to `GoogleService-Info-prod`and `GoogleService-Info-dev`. and tried to read the files directly:

```
#if Production
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-prod", ofType: "plist"),
           let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
        } else {
            fatalError("GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist is missing!")
        }
#elseif Development
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-dev", ofType: "plist"),
           let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
        } else {
            fatalError("GoogleService-Info.plist is missing!")
        }
#endif

        FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { _, _ in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

App can run ok after that. But in logs I have this warning

```
[FirebaseCore][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
```

So It can mean that filename must be `GoogleService-Info.plist` and it doesn't work with `GoogleService-Info-prod` and `GoogleService-Info-dev`

---

In my second attempt, I made all the two files to `GoogleService-Info.plist`, so it leads to have an error:

```
"Multiple commands produce GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

To avoid this error, I removed these two files from **Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources**

and make the firebase setup function like that:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
        
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
 let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { _, _ in }
 application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

And then add this script

```
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Application/Firebase/Dev/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Application/Firebase/Prod/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

# Make sure the dev version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV ]
then
    echo "No Development GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure the prod version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD ]
then
    echo "No Production GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo "Will copy ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} to final destination: ${PLIST_DESTINATION}"

# Copy over the prod GoogleService-Info.plist for Release builds
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]
then
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
else
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
fi
```

BTW: I have to check the `For install builds only`, otherwise I will get error:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Then after run, app will crash, and it says firebase cannot find `GoogleService-Info.plist`- it's because I remove then from **Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources** to avoid multiple file name issue.

Can anyone help how to fix this issue and add google files successfully.

BTW: I don't care about any Firebase analytics

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented this in one of the apps I worked on. You're close to solving it. The way I did it was to add different `GoogleService-Info.plist` files in my project (I had 4 schemes and added 4 files) under separate folders. These files were not included in any target (all targets unchecked in Target Membership under Identity Inspector), they were just a part of the project.

I wrote a build phase script to copy the appropriate file based on my configuration (which in-turn is linked to my schemes) to the build. Here's an abridged version of the script that will give you an idea of how to go about it

```bash
FILENAME=GoogleService-Info.plist

DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "MY_CONFIG_1" ]
then
    CONFIGFILE1=${PROJECT_DIR}/MYPROJ/CONFIG1DIRECTORY/${FILENAME}
    
    if [ ! -f $CONFIGFILE1 ]
    then
        echo "File not found"
        exit 1
    fi
    
    cp "${CONFIGFILE1}" "${DESTINATION}"
    
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "MY_CONFIG_2" ]
then
    CONFIGFILE2=${PROJECT_DIR}/MYPROJ/CONFIG2DIRECTORY/${FILENAME}
    
    if [ ! -f $CONFIGFILE2 ]
    then
        echo "File not found"
        exit 1
    fi
    
    cp "${CONFIGFILE2}" "${DESTINATION}"
    
fi
```

The key here is that I'm using the name `GoogleService-Info.plist` for all 4 files, and just copying the required one to the app while building.

Comment: This is the type of solution what I was looking for. But somehow it's not working for me. I dont get any error in the build phase but app crashes at runtime. It's like the file is still not included in the target during runtime

Comment: @WaqarAhmed - Sorry I haven't been visiting SO quite often in the past so I may be late in responding to you, but have you ensured the part where I mentioned "These files were not included in any target (all targets unchecked in Target Membership under Identity Inspector)"? If you do not exclude all the files then your app will crash on building [this is what I remember happening to me when I was working on this]. If you have been able to resolve this already then I'm happy for you.